# why the divs shrink while using display :flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

why the divs shrink while using display :flex .I want to scroll my divs horizontally .but it not taking width height `100` and `100`?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: flex: 0 1 auto; 1 = shrink = enabled

Comment: or you set flex-shrink to 0, or you set a min-width to 100px ... children shrinking is the defaut behavior

Comment: It depends on what you want with your css. Flex has a default of disabling element from wrapping. If you want  you boxes to keep your format I suggest enabling flex-wrap. Also you can disable flex-shrink. Check the flex documentation for more info.